# Calculate the optimum contribution to Provident Fund(PF) account

Tags: income-tax, india, retirement, calculation

I am fresh out of college and started working and want to work out how much I should contribute to my Provident Fund account to maximize the benefit from tax deductions.

I am from India, so for those from other countries:

> A Provident Fund is a retirement account for which I have to make a minimum contribution of 12% of my basic salary. The company has to also contribute a minimum of 12% of my basic to the account.
>   
> The maximum contribution I can make is 88% of my basic salary. But only upto Rs. 100,000 is exempted from tax.

Now I want to compute how much I should contribute myself to the PF to enjoy the tax benefit. I will illustrate what logic I came up with to solve the question, but the answer I reached seems too insane to be right. So I hope someone can point out what I'm doing wrong here.

```
Current rate of interest on PF account = r% per annum
Current market rate of interest = m% per annum
Tax rate on my earnings (which could go into a PF account) = 30%
Let my EXTRA contribution to the PF account be x.
Therefore, tax deducted amount on it (assuming I hadn't put it in the PF) = 0.7x

In order for it to be profitable to contribute EXTRA to the PF:
Value of EXTRA contribution 1 year from now at PF account rate > 
       Value of EXTRA contribution after tax 1 year from now at market rate
```

Thus, the boundary condition will be given by:
[image: equation]

The solution to this equation is:
[image: solution]

This seems crazy high to be right; at the current PF rate `ideal m ~= 45%` that's why I really suspect my approach is all wrong. What went wrong, and how can I approach such problems?

NOTE: While advise on things I may have misunderstood about PF and its workings are much appreciated, the main aim of this question is to try and understand how such problems can be worked out in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not inherently wrong, but a little bit myopic. You try to perform better than the tax of 30% in 1 year that's why you have a constant of 36.2029 in your equation. You should think of investing money for a long-term since you get your pension much later.
 Then your solution would be

```
m = 1.03017r + 1200*(0.7^(-1/(12*N)) - 1)
```

Which has a constant of 36.2029 for N=1, however for N=20 your equation would look like this:

```
m = 1.7847 + 1.03017r
```

Besides, this works only if you can change your decision each month on how much you contribute. If you have to commit (do you?), the equation would look a little bit more complicated.

Comment: Thanks Max. I understand last comment; in fact, the PF does have a lock in period. What I was looking for is verification of my maths, since the output looked really crazy. I hadn't tried to scale to a longer term, and must admit the huge difference in `m` is really surprising.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over complicating this.

Currently your PF is lets say 0.
The max exemption on investment into PF is Rs 1,00,000/- .
So if you have 100,000 to invest into PF vs lets say a Bank FD for a year;
You will get 12% [I think its 9% these days] on Rs 1,00,000/-.
FD You will get around say 7% on 70,000/- [Balance 30 K is tax amount].

So for the first Rs 100,000 it makes sense to put into PF if otherwise you are putting the money into Fixed Deposits. However if you are investing into other tax savings schemes, its not beneficial only to the extent of rates.

The second benefit is the rate different, the PF gives a better rate than FD. PF interest is not taxed, but FD is taxed. So beyond Rs 100,000 the question really is given the PF interest rate is x% can you invest into something at y% less of taxes making it more than X% return.

Ofcouse no investments can be compared like for like, there are risk / liquidity and other considerations.

Comment: Actually, for the case of after Rs. 100,000 it is just a matter of choosing the higher interest rate (since the principle is still the same; both tax deducted). But within the first 1 lakh, it becomes a matter of ensuring that the FD (or other market) rate on a tax deducted amount returns more than the PF rate on full amount.

Comment: The interest of say Rs 10,000 earned on PF is tax free. Where as the interest of say Rs 10,000 is taxable and hence you only get 7,000. So the interest rate has to be higher by the tax percentage.